# Issues instantiating Node.js for our chat feature in apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, .htaccess, sockets

We're having an amazing problem with Node.js not instantiating after installing SSL on our servers. We've tried many things & I'm personally not that well versed in apache or Node.js. Below is the error and few things we've tried. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is our domain.com.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain.com-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /socket.io http://192.237.xxx.xxx:8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAdmin info@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain.com-ssl-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain.com-ssl-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /var/cert/www_domain_com.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile    /var/cert/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cert/www_domain_com.key

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /socket.io http://192.237.xxx.xxx:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://192.237.xxx.xxx:8080

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's our .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex testindex index.html index.php index.shtml index.htm
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# ditch index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript
```

And last, but not least instantiating our socket.io

```
socket : io.connect('https://domain.com/socket.io', {secure: true}),
```

With that setup we had this error.

[image: >>>]

Then we changed how we instantiated our socket.io (after a friend's suggestion) to

```
socket : io.connect('https://domain.com:8080/socket.io', {secure: true}),
```

And we got this below

[image: this]

After doing some research we enabled CORS on our server by adding this line to our above mentioned .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But, still the same error... (mod_headers are installed).

We have pretty much pulled all our hair and hoping someone had the same problem that could help us out.

///

Per request here's socket.js in its entirety:

```
$(function(){

  window.MY_Socket = {


    // Instantiate the Socket.IO client and connect to the server
    socket : io.connect('https://domain.com:8080/socket.io', {secure: true}),


    // Set up the initial event handlers for the Socket.IO client
    bindEvents : function() {
        this.socket.on('startup',MY_Socket.startupMessage);
        //this.socket.on('startup',MY_Socket.startupComment);
        this.socket.on('broadcastNewPost',MY_Socket.updateMessages);
        this.socket.on('broadcastNewComment',MY_Socket.updateComment);
        this.socket.on('broadcastNewChat',MY_Socket.updateChat);
    },

    // This just indicates that a Socket.IO connection has begun.
    startupMessage : function(data) {
      //console.log(data.message);
    },

    startupComment : function(data) {
      //console.log(data.message);
    },

    // on 'broadcastNewPost' update the message list from other users
    updateMessages : function(data) {
        // Because the message is broadcasted twice (once for the team, again for the admins)
        // we need to make sure it is only displayed once if the Admin is also on the same
        // team as the sender.
        //if( ( !userIsAnAdmin() && data.team != 'admin') ||
        //  ( userIsAnAdmin() && data.team === 'admin') ){
        //console.log("TEAM " + data.team);
        //console.log(session_co_id);
        if(data.team == session_co_id) {
            // Send the html partial with the new message over to the jQuery function that will display it.
            App.showBroadcastedMessage(data.message);
        }
    },

    updateComment : function(data) {
        // Because the message is broadcasted twice (once for the team, again for the admins)
        // we need to make sure it is only displayed once if the Admin is also on the same
        // team as the sender.
        //if( ( !userIsAnAdmin() && data.team != 'admin') ||
        //  ( userIsAnAdmin() && data.team === 'admin') ){
        if(data.team == session_co_id) {
        // Send the html partial with the new message over to the jQuery function that will display it.
        App.showBroadcastedComment(data.message, data.team, data.status);
      }
    },

    updateChat : function(data) {
        //console.log("TEAM " + data.team);
        //console.log(session_co_id);
        //if(data.co_id == session_co_id) {
            // Send the html partial with the new message over to the jQuery function that will display it.
            // post: post, diss_id: diss_id, last_sender: last_sender, co_id: co_id
            //console.log(data.diss_id);

            App.showBroadcastedChat(data.first_name, data.html, data.broadcast_post, data.profile_picture, data.diss_id, data.last_poster, data.session_co_id);
        //}
    },

    // This will emit an html partial containing a new message,
    // plus the teamId of the user sending the message.

    sendNewComment : function(msg,team,status) {
      MY_Socket.socket.emit('newComment',msg,team,status);
    },

    sendNewChat : function(first_name, html, broadcast_post, profile_picture, diss_id, last_poster, session_co_id) {

        MY_Socket.socket.emit('newChat', first_name, html, broadcast_post, profile_picture, diss_id, last_poster, session_co_id);
    },

    sendDiscussionNewComment : function(msg,team,status) {
      MY_Socket.socket.emit('newDiscussionComment', msg, team, status);
    },

    sendNewPost : function(msg,team) {

        MY_Socket.socket.emit('newPost',msg,team);
    },

    // Join a socket.io 'room' based on the user's team
    joinRoom : function(session_co_id){
      // get the CodeIgniter sessionID from the cookie
      //var sessionId = readCookie('ci_session');
        sessionId = session_co_id; //1  // CHANGE IT ******************************************************
        //console.log(sessionId);
      if(sessionId) {
        // Send the sessionID to the Node server in an effort to join a 'room'
        MY_Socket.socket.emit('joinRoom', session_co_id);
      } else {
        // If no sessionID exists, don't try to join a room.
        //console.log('No session id found. Broadcast disabled.');
        //forward to logout url?
      }
    }

  } // end window.MY_Socket

  // Start it up!
  MY_Socket.bindEvents();

    // Read a cookie. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

});
```

Comment: Your friend's suggestion to use port 8080 presumably bypasses the Apache proxy (which is running on port 80) and creates the cross origin issues by accessing Node.js directly (since different ports are different domains). Since you were getting a 200 against /socket.io/1/?t=000 you seem to be getting from Apache to Node OK. I might shift your focus from Apache to Node - can you post your node code? I assume your client code would go back to `socket : io.connect('https://domain.com/socket.io', {secure: true}),`

Comment: also note that your http and https configurations are different... I might just try to get this working with HTTP only then add HTTPS.

Comment: This was working fine on HTTP // and we're not utilizing http at all now, since the app is served on HTTPS // I've updated my question with the entire socket.js content.